# Best practice displaying content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am working on a web app, and I have considered hiding or display some content/options using CSS or stamping it in dynamically using an AJAX requests as needed. However, I can also stamp everything in at the time of load and just use CSS to hide or display the content as needed.I know it can mean a busier DOM, but it seems like CSS would be snappier than an AJAX request. What are the pros and cons of this? Your recommendations would be greatly appreciated as well as explanations about why you recommended what you recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the content up front and don't need to dynamically load it based on user input, definitely load it into semantically reasonable places in the DOM and then show or hide it with CSS.

Here are some reasons:

1. People with Javascript disabled will still be able to get all the content
2. Making extra trips just to make the page AJAXy seems silly, the real killer is the number of HTTP requests, keep that low

Here's some negatives:

1. Exactly as you said, the DOM gets messy, and it's not very good to have a bunch of hidden content that a screen reader might pick up.
2. You can't deliver modified content if the state of something has changed between when they loaded the page and clicked a button. AJAX lets you serve the absolute freshest content, and that ability is gone.

So really it comes down to:

- Does your target audience ever have Javascript turned off, or *could* they?
- Are you worried about the load on a user's browser from multiple HTTP requests?
- Does your target audience view your website with screen readers where the hidden content would cause confusing audio fragments, or *could* they?
- Does the content being placed into the page change frequently enough to merit an AJAX call?

The answers to those questions should drive your design one way or the other.

Comment: I don't think we should support a bunch of people who disable javascript ;)

Comment: I agree. I would think about the page as content first. The screen reader will get all of it, and then you can hide and show, in a progressively enhancing sort of style. Most small sites, only really need one page, and this is a great way to keep it easy to interact with. Tabs are a good example, but keeping them responsive is key.

Comment: I was fooling around in this vein the other day: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/43dc388c639c2f1f2623d0e43d29e229  - might interest you. has javascript off by default. and while I don't think that people without should be first priority, the content is all there if they need it, then run it to see a spa-like experience.

Comment: Though the "small sites only really need one page" is absolutelly true. There are some huge backdraws with this approach considering SEO(search engine optimization). For examle you are stripping yourself of having multiple <title> tags where all of them are taken into consideration and so on. So be careful if you want your webpage to be displayed somewhere to top in google search result.

Comment: You cannot forget people not using JavaScript. It's almost as common as having JavaScript on. PHP.net made a change on their website a while ago and people sent complaints about it. Most offices don't use JS by default for "security reasons". You can't just overrule people that are forced to not use JS. Same goes to browsers. Offices can use IE6-IE8 and blame "security efficiency" for it even though they're wrong. I still must make my site available for them. That's the main rule: availability and the ease of use for everybody. Don't be too lazy.

Comment: I appreciate all of your answers, they were all useful.